# dijit tree seleted node icon change

Tags: dojo, tree, styles

I am using dojo version 1.10.2 and claro theme.

I do not want folder icon for tree node, which I have achieved using getIconClass. Now I have requirement to highlight the selected node with closefolder(or any other image) in front of node and color of the node label 'red'.  I am able to change color of the node label, but not able to display the image in front of selected node. Please advice me to resolve the same.
the fiddle link is given below:

http://jsfiddle.net/pyz9Lcpv/1/

```
require([
"dojo/_base/window", "dojo/store/Memory",
"dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel", "dijit/Tree",
"dojo/domReady!"
```

], function(win, Memory, ObjectStoreModel, Tree){

```
// Create test store, adding the getChildren() method required by ObjectStoreModel
var myStore = new Memory({
    data: [
        { id: 'world', name:'The earth', type:'planet', population: '6 billion'},
        { id: 'AF', name:'Africa', type:'continent', population:'900 million', area: '30,221,532 sq km',
                timezone: '-1 UTC to +4 UTC', parent: 'world'},
            { id: 'EG', name:'Egypt', type:'country', parent: 'AF' },
            { id: 'KE', name:'Kenya', type:'country', parent: 'AF' },
                { id: 'Nairobi', name:'Nairobi', type:'city', parent: 'KE' },
                { id: 'Mombasa', name:'Mombasa', type:'city', parent: 'KE' },
            { id: 'SD', name:'Sudan', type:'country', parent: 'AF' },
                { id: 'Khartoum', name:'Khartoum', type:'city', parent: 'SD' },
        { id: 'AS', name:'Asia', type:'continent', parent: 'world' },
            { id: 'CN', name:'China', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
            { id: 'IN', name:'India', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
            { id: 'RU', name:'Russia', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
            { id: 'MN', name:'Mongolia', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
        { id: 'OC', name:'Oceania', type:'continent', population:'21 million', parent: 'world'},
        { id: 'EU', name:'Europe', type:'continent', parent: 'world' },
            { id: 'DE', name:'Germany', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
            { id: 'FR', name:'France', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
            { id: 'ES', name:'Spain', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
            { id: 'IT', name:'Italy', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
        { id: 'NA', name:'North America', type:'continent', parent: 'world' },
        { id: 'SA', name:'South America', type:'continent', parent: 'world' }
    ],
    getChildren: function(object){
        return this.query({parent: object.id});
    }
});

// Create the model
var myModel = new ObjectStoreModel({
    store: myStore,
    query: {id: 'world'}
});

// Create the Tree.
var tree = new Tree({
    model: myModel,
    getIconClass:function(item, opened){
            console.log('tree getIconClass', item, opened);
            console.log('tree item type', item.type);
        },
    onClick: function(item, node) {
            node._iconClass= "dijitFolderClosed";
            node.iconNode.className = "dijitFolderClosed";
            console.log("node : " +node);

        }
});
tree.placeAt(contentHere);
tree.startup();
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change the icon via css, for example, this will change the icon on the selected tree node to a gradient:

```
.claro .dijitTreeRowSelected .dijitTreeExpando {
    background-image: url("http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/checkout/dijit/themes/claro/images/standardGradient.png");
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

Here is the updated jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/pyz9Lcpv/4/